# How to convert this string to an array of ints?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

How to convert this string to dict in python ?

```
[[[0,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,5],  [1,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,4],  [2,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,3],  [2,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,3],  [3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,2],  [3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,2],  [3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,2],  [3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,2],  [3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,2],  [4,3,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,1],  [4,3,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,1],  [4,3,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,1],  [5,4,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0],  [5,4,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0],  [6,5,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0],  [6,5,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0],  [6,5,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0],  [5,4,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]]]
```

it supposed to be like this

```
[[0,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,5],  [1,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,4],  [2,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,3],  [2,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,3],  [3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,2],  [3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,2],  [3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,2],  [3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,2],  [3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,2],  [4,3,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,1],  [4,3,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,1],  [4,3,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,1],  [5,4,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0],  [5,4,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0],  [6,5,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0],  [6,5,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0],  [6,5,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0],  [5,4,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on ur question, I can't see where's the dict you're trying to create

Comment: the first item is a string, I need it to be array of int array

Comment: Are you trying to flatten the existing list further?

Comment: The first item, as shown in your question is an array of arrays of int arrays - or in python terms, a list of lists of list, and not a string.

Comment: I want to use traveler salesman greedy algorithm on matrix and the data comes in format of string and I do not know hot to read it in matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure where the dictionary is coming into play, but you can do something like this to get the desired output:

```
from ast import literal_eval

arr_string = '[[[0,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,5],  [1,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,4],  [2,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,3],  [2,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,3],  [3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,2],  [3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,2],  [3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,2],  [3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,2],  [3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,2],  [4,3,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,1],  [4,3,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,1],  [4,3,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,1],  [5,4,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0],  [5,4,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0],  [6,5,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0],  [6,5,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0],  [6,5,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0],  [5,4,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]]]'

result = [arr for arr in literal_eval(arr_string)[0]]
print(result)   # [[0,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,5],  [1,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,4],  [2,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,3],  [2,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,3],  [3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,2],  [3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,2],  [3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,2],  [3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,2],  [3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,2],  [4,3,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,1],  [4,3,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,1],  [4,3,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,1],  [5,4,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0],  [5,4,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0],  [6,5,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0],  [6,5,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0],  [6,5,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0],  [5,4,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```